# Setting hyperlink as underline on hover (with no shadow effect)

Tags: css, wordpress, anchor, bbpress

I have this styling:

```
#bbpress-forums li.bbp-forum-freshness a:hover, #bbpress-forums li.bbp-topic-freshness a:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
  -moz-box-shadow: none !important;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none !important;
  box-shadow: none !important;
}
```

Yet, when I hover over the links:

[image: Links]

As you can see they are still showing shadow effects. I have been able to use the aforementioned approach in other classes.

The page:

https://www.publictalksoftware.co.uk/support-forums/

Any advice appreciated. I just want it to be a underline with no shadow.

Comment: Please provide the shortest HTML required to re-produce this in addition to the CSS you've already provided. See [Minimal, Reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
.bbp-forum-title:hover, .bbp-forum-freshness a:hover {
background: transparent!important;
border-top: none!important;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this. Works well. :)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it's a background color, not a box shadow.

Try to add to your class :

```
background: none;
border: none;
```

And you dont need to reset `box-shadow`.

Comment: Thanks for this and for clarifying I did not need the `box-shadow` styling.